# PHP Opendir() paths containing spaces

Tags: php

I want to open a directory on linux file system using the `opendir()` PHP function.

The path might contain spaces or some other special characters.

While I am trying to open the directory I get:

```
Warning: opendir(/home/user/_demo/test/salamis\ test): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

I firstly tried to replace the space character with `\` (slash space) using:

```
str_replace(" ","\ ","salamis test");
```

But unfortunately is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried `opendir("/home/user/_demo/test/salamis test");` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose path parameter within quotes (double or single).

e.g.

```
opendir('/home/user/_demo/test/salamis test');
opendir("/home/user/_demo/test/salamis test");

$path = '/home/user/_demo/test/salamis test';
opendir($path);

$path = "/home/user/_demo/test/salamis test";
opendir($path);
```

Comment: If he wasn't enclosing that path in quotes, he would get a parse error. The script wouldn't even run.

Comment: @webbiedave I am guessing he is including `\\` before spaces.

Comment: Necro-commenting but this is not the solution. It doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem today.  I found that adding the quotes did not help.  I realized that the share folder was mounted with a different user account, and after umounting and updating /etc/fstab with the correct uid & gid (apache), I was able to mount and process files on the share.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889867/mount-shared-folder-vbox-as-another-user) was also helpful.